# Wordpress is not sending emails to Gmail

Tags: php, wordpress, gmail, exim

None of my Wordpress emails are sent to Gmail. More info:

- I am using EXIM mail server
- I am using wordpress latest version
- it happens only when emails are sent to Gmail

EXIM logs say that the email is sent succesfully to Gmail, but they are not sent, or sent in spam.

Comment: Gmail as smarthost or gmail as MX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a combination of factors:

- EXIM, unlike postfix, is not automatically setting the `Sender` header
- Gmail recently made some changes to deal with spam better, and if the email headers are missing the `Sender` header, it will most likely silently discard it, or send it as spam.
- Wordpress doesn't set the `Sender` header

Once you know these, the fix is quite simple. If you are using Wordpress, the quick and dirty way to do it is to go to `wp-includes/pluggable.php`, look for the `wp_mail()` function search for:

```
$phpmailer->From     = apply_filters( 'wp_mail_from'     , $from_email );
```

then add the following right after it:

```
$phpmailer->Sender   = $phpmailer->From;
```

**Once you do this, emails will work, and you can fix the problem the proper way, without overwriting the core, by writing a plugin.** Wordpress uses [phpmailer](https://phpmailer.worxware.com) which knows about this issue, but wordpress doesn't use it. There is also a [bug report](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22837) on this issue.

To fix the problem using the core [mail()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function, you have to do the following:

```
// $sender can be the same email address as the From header
mail($to, $subject, $message, $additional_headers, "-f {$sender}")
```

There is another option that may work, depending on the configuration of your server (I couldn't test it, would love if someone could test this):

```
$sendmailFrom = ini_get('sendmail_path');
ini_set('sendmail_path', $sendmailFrom . ' -f sender@mysite.com'); // or whatever you want
```

Comment: RFC5322 states that `Sender:` is redundant when the content would match `From:`  any system requiring a `Sender:` that matches `From:` is broken beyond credibility.

Comment: @Jasen Wow, you're raising the dead :-) This was >3 years ago, not sure if it's still true.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail (and likely Hotmail and Yahoo eventually) is [starting to disable traditional SMTP authentication mechanisms](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.ca/2014/04/new-security-measures-will-affect-older.html) (PLAIN, LOGIN and CRAMMD5) in favour of OAUTH2.

If you send mail with WordPress (PHPMailer) alone, Gmail will discard it or mark it as SPAM. If you send mail with a typical WordPress SMTP plugin, Gmail will give you an authentication error, or make you jump through hoops like application-specific passwords, two-factor authentication, and enabling less secure apps as an account setting.

The first plugin to implement OAuth 2.0 for WordPress (disclaimer, I am the author) is [Postman SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/postman-smtp/). If port TCP 465 allows outbound connections to Gmail, your WordPress emails will be delivered by Postman without error.